# Not implemented error when calling method of class

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, oop, methods, constructor

I'm getting this error when I try to call the method of class. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong

```
class KickstarterModel:

    def __init__(self):

        self.model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
        self.X_train = None
        self.y_train = None


    def preprocess_training_data(self, df):

        y_train = df['state'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'failed' else 1)

        numerical_columns = df.describe().columns
        X = df[numerical_columns].copy()
        X.set_index('id', inplace=True)

        X["dif_launched_created"] = X.launched_at - X.created_at
        X["dif_deadline_created"] = X.deadline - X.created_at
        X["dif_deadline_launched"] = X.deadline - X.launched_at
        X['goal_in_usd'] = X.goal * X.static_usd_rate

        X.drop(['deadline', 'created_at', 'launched_at', 'goal', 'static_usd_rate'], axis=1, inplace=True)

        X_train = X
        y_train = y
```

Error message:

```
NotImplementedError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-18acf6b32d72> in <module>()
      1 model = KickstarterModel()
      2 
----> 3 model.preprocess_training_data(df)

~\OneDrive\Documents\Cambridge Spark\Module 3\model.py in preprocess_training_data(self, df)
      7         self.y_train = None
      8 
----> 9 
     10     def preprocess_training_data(self, df):
     11 

NotImplementedError:
```

Comment: You need to give us the code that raise this exception

Comment: It looks like you probably edited your code after you imported it in ipython. Ipython will cache your imports and will not adapt imported modules if the source code changes.  You should restart your ipython shell and try again and see if the problem persists. You should also check out ipython's [autoreload](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html?highlight=autoreload) extension for the future.